# Skype and problem with terminal

Tags: command-line, skype

Recently, I have installed ubuntu 13.04, and updated it.
I want to install skype. I search in "ubuntu software center" but I did not find anything. Therefore, I search on internet. I found out some commands for skype installation.
Then, I open the terminal and type the command. it request for password. The problem is that when i want to enter my password, my keyboard did not work and I can not type my password.
How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you type your password for `sudo` it won't appear,don't consider it a keyboard problem. If all your keys on the keyboard were working it means that there was no problem with your keyboard.

If some keys which was essential for typing the password weren't working then your best option is `onboard`. Search for the `onboard` application in Dash. It will allow you to type in the password without using the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Installation of Skype requires a little bit more work since it is closed-source proprietary software. It can be found in the Ubuntu Software Center only if the "Canonical Partners" repository is enabled. You can do this in many different ways: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype The easiest way for you is via the Ubuntu Software Center -> Edit -> Software Sources. There you have to check the box next to "Canonical Partners" in the "Other Software" tab. Btw your problem with typing in the terminal (at least from the scarce info that you have given us) does NOT seem connected to Skype itself (since it is not even installed on your system).

A piece of advice: don't just write any command you find on the internet even if the one who posted it states that it IS the solution. Always check and double-check. Also when you post a question like this without giving ANY useful information the probability that you get a (quick) reply decreases a lot. When you say that you have "typed in some command" the people who come here to see your question in detail with the intend to answer it start scratching their heads "What command? Where did he/she find it?". Frankly I needed to read 2-3 times your question in order to (maybe) understand what you want to do, which omho is a waste of time (my time at least).

Answer (score 0):

What both previous answers got right is that that the command was probably `sudo`. (As it requires a password and won't show it onscreen being typed.)

What both answers failed to mention is that this is being done by `sudo` **on purpose**. This is so that you can safely type in your password even if someone's watching over your shoulder (the proper term is shoulder-surfing) at an airport or a coffee shop or whatever.

Comment: You might be right. Still it's hard to decode the question. :P Btw there is a way to show asteriks (don't know for plain text) when typing your password in the terminal by editing the sudoers file. Run "sudo visudo" in your terminal and it will open the sudoers file in Vim.  Adding ",pwfeedback" to "Defaults" turns of the asteriks-feedback feature. :)